# Why is all case statements execute in a switch case after a matching condition ,when not using break; in PHP

Tags: php, switch-statement, case-statement

Hi i can understand what is going on here , but want to know the purpose ,

in this switch case statement

```
<?php
switch(1) {
case 1: print("Book Details<br />");
case 2: print("Book Author<br />");
default: print("Missing Book<br />");
}
?>
```

the result is

```
Book Details
Book Author
Missing Book
```

my expected result was

```
Book Details
Missing Book
```

My question is that

*in switch statement we are checking `switch(1)` , so how is it possible to execute `case 2:`
 default should print and i can understand that .
is there any particular reason to this ?

please explain , thanks in advance .

Comment: You may want to remove the codeigniter tag as this question doesn't relate to that specifically.

Comment: @Jeremy Miller  did that :)

Answer (score 1):

Read the documentation paragraph after [Example #2](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)

> It is important to understand how the switch statement is executed in
>   order to avoid mistakes. The switch statement executes line by line
>   (actually, statement by statement). In the beginning, no code is
>   executed. Only when a case statement is found with a value that
>   matches the value of the switch expression does PHP begin to execute
>   the statements. PHP continues to execute the statements until the end
>   of the switch block, or the first time it sees a break statement. If
>   you don't write a break statement at the end of a case's statement
>   list, PHP will go on executing the statements of the following case.

3 examples then follow showing the effect of `break` and the role of `default`

Answer (score 1):

Like you mentioned in the question it depends on the break statement. The reason is maybe someone wants to have 2 or more cases with the same result and another one with a different.

Something like:

```
<?php
switch($aVar) {
case 1:
case 2: print("Both cases show this sentence");
        break;
case 3: print("This case shows a different one.");
        break;
default:
        print("No matching case");
        break;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is knows as fall through. Due to the absence of **break** statement, PHP continues to execute the statements until the end of the switch block.
Therefore you should use switch case in following format:

```
switch (n) {
 case label1:
   code to be executed if n=label1;
   break;
  case label2:
    code to be executed if n=label2;
    break;
 case label3:
    code to be executed if n=label3;
    break;
 default:
    code to be executed if n is different from all labels; 
}
```

Use break to prevent the code from running into the next case automatically.